# Create pdf file in Android app

Tags: android, itext

I want to create one pdf file file from my register view data. I have searched for creating pdf file in Android. I mainly found 2 solution for creating it.

```
 1) Use iText library 2) using DroidText
```

I have to generate 2 tables in my pdf file. And i found that it will be easy to use iText for this  while searching but i need licence version of it for that purpose. Is it true?

My question is if it is so, then which will be feasible solution to create pdf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`iText` is free, unless you want to buy the license that provides advantages not available with the open-source AGPL license

source: http://itextpdf.com/pricing